# "VGACON disables amdgpu modesetting" error while upgrading ubuntu 20.04->22.04

Tags: upgrade

I'm updating from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04(from Ubuntu directly, not installing with external media), and after the last upgrade step where it restarts, it shows this message, then just black screen(with a blinking cursor)

```
scci ...: Wrong diagnostic page: asked for 1 got 8    
scci ...: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1  
...      : Failed to bind enclosure -19
/dev/sdb1: clean, ...files, ...blocks...
... *ERROR* VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesetting.
```

I've tried editing the boot command (by selecting "Ubuntu" and then pressing `e` to add to the end of the `linux` line `amdgpu.dc=0` then pressing `ctrl+x` to boot

For next step should I try

- Updating kernel? (not sure how to do that before booting)
- Update Graphics driver (also not sure how to do that before booting)

specs:

- ryzen 7 2700x
- rx 570

thanks!